# password_verify doesn't work, even though it has the hash and the user's password

Tags: php, authentication, passwords

I'm writing log in code for the only user in my `db`. 
But the `password_verify` function doesn't seem to work. When I `echo` both the `hash` from the `db` and the `password` written in the form, I see them, so there's no problem with the query or the `$_POST`.

Here's my code:
the log in:

```
$passwordFromForm = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
$nmbr = 12; // it's the user's id.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE iduser = $nmbr";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
// $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $hashFromDB = $row['hash'];
}
if(password_verify($passwordFromForm, $hashFromDB)) {
    echo "success";
    header("Location: ../admin.php");
}
else {
    echo "The hash is:" . $hashFromDB . "and the pass is:" . $passwordFromForm;
    //this echoes the correct hash and string
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The function password_verify() is dependent with password_hash(), you can check the algorithm password_hash() used whether the same with password_verify(), check the res with password_get_info($hash)

Comment: Thanks!

If password_verify's hash is the same as the password_hash's one? 
They are the same.

Comment: Here's the password_get_info:

array(3) { ["algo"]=> int(1) ["algoName"]=> string(6) "bcrypt" ["options"]=> array(1) { ["cost"]=> int(12) } }

Answer (score 1):

You should not do any escaping of the password, before feeding it to the `password_hash()` / `password_verify()` function. So remove the call to `htmlspecialchars()` and make sure that your database field holding the hash, is of type `varchar(255)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I already tried without htmlspecialchars(), and the database is VARCHAR(255), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @TheTryHardz - Could you give an example of the content of `$hashFromDB`?

Comment: On my code, when I echo $hashFromDB the output is the hash $2y$10$oPHWLB.6Z0hBvjk8al24xuiG7Io4l7ERGCtLnW5Eij1wTlT67mLJW.

Comment: @TheTryHardz - The hash look fine, what means that the PHP version and the database access cannot be the problem (i understand that you read the value from the db?). So the only possible problem can be the input. You said that you tried without the `htmlspecialchars()` function, did you remove this in the registration form as well and did you store a new password before testing the login?

Comment: martinstoeckli, i did, and nothing happened. Ended up solving the problem by basically rebuilding the log in. Never new what went wrong.